# Multiplying Last Row from One Sheet and Placing Onto Other Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to multiply 2 column's last 3 rows of "production_units" by "production_cost" by each other from my sheet called "DATA" and placing them in a sheet called "Report" under the column title "Production Cost". I've been trying but to no avail. Thanks.

My spreadsheets look like this:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
Sheets("DATA").Activate
' Use this lRow now since the previous one require you to be in a With   loop
Range(Cells(lRow - 2, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)).Copy

With Sheets("Report")
.Activate
' Pastes the last 3 cells of Column A into the Month column
.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
.Range("B8").Formula = "Month"
.Range("C8").Formula = "Production Cost"
' Calculates the Production cost
.Range(.Cells(lRow - 3, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy
.Range("C9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C11")
' Calculates the Inventory cost
.Range("C14").Select
.Range("D8").Formula = "Inventory Cost"
.Range("E8").Formula = "Total Cost"
.Range("B12").Formula = "Total"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly have you been trying? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Put it in the post. Thought I had done so. The problem I believe is that the sheet  "DATA" I want data to be read from is not activated.

Comment: No need to activate it... did you try: `Sheets("DATA").Range("A" & lRow - 2 & ":A" & lRow).Copy`?

Comment: I did try that but to no avail. The cells where values are supposed to be placed remain empty.

Comment: For copying, tray this piece of code: `Dim shD As Worksheet` 
  `Set shD = Sheets("DATA")`   
  `shD.Range(shD.Cells(lRow - 2, 1), shD.Cells(lRow, 1)).Copy Sheets("Report").Range("B9")`. Attention: `Sheets("Report").Range("B9")` must be  on the same row with the copy part. Only separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your code. You may like to look at the syntax.

```
    Dim WsData As Worksheet
Dim WsReport As Worksheet
Dim Rl As Long                          ' last row
Dim Rng As Range

Set WsData = Worksheets("Data")
Set WsReport = Worksheets("Report")

With WsData
    ' look for the last used cell in column B
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Rl - 2, 1), .Cells(Rl, 1))
    ' Pastes the last 3 cells of Column A into the Month column
    Rng.Copy Destination:=WsReport.Cells(9, "B")
End With

With WsReport
    .Cells(8, "B").Formula = "Month"
    .Cells(8, "C").Formula = "Production Cost"
    .Cells(8, "D").Formula = "Month"
    .Cells(8, "E").Formula = "Inventory Cost"
    .Cells(8, "F").Formula = "Total cost"
    .Cells(12, "B").Formula = "Total"

    ' Calculates the Production cost
    '   there is no calculation unless there are formulas being copied
    Rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=.Cells(9, "C")

    ' Calculates the Inventory cost
    '   there is no calculation
End With
```

Of course, all the calculations are missing because they are not included in your question. I hope you will be able to add them to the code I have provided.