# Multiplying Last 3 Cells of One Sheet and Placing Them in Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to accomplish: 
- Multiply the last 3 cells of columns B & C in sheet "DATA"
- Place these values in cells C9:C11 in sheet "Report"
- The issues is I don't know how to tell Excel to do this and move those values to another sheet.

This is the code I have to do it so far:

```
' Calculates the Production cost
.Range(.Cells(lRow - 3, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy
.Range("C9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C11")
```

Rest of my code:

```
Sheets("DATA").Activate
' Use this lRow now since the previous one require you to be in a With loop
Range(Cells(lRow - 2, 1), Cells(lRow, 1)).Copy

With Sheets("Report")
.Activate
' Pastes the last 3 cells of Column A into the Month column
.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 13.71
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 13.71
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 13.71
.Range("B8").Formula = "Month"
.Range("C8").Formula = "Production Cost"
.Range("A14").Formula = "Figure below illustrates the production unit, and the demand time series for the past year; as well as the forecast for the following three months."
.Range("A28").Formula = "Figure below illustrates the inventory levels for the past year, as well as the forecast for the following three months."
.Range("A42").Formula = "Regards,"
' Calculates the Production cost
.Range(.Cells(lRow - 3, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy
.Range("C9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C11")
' Calculates the Inventory cost
.Range("C14").Select
.Range("D8").Formula = "Inventory Cost"
.Range("E8").Formula = "Total Cost"
.Range("B12").Formula = "Total"
' Sums Production Cost for the last 3 months
.Range("C12").Formula = "=SUM(C9:C11)"
' Fills in the adjacent cells to the right
.Range("C12").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C12:E12"), Type:=xlFillDefault
' Sums Production and Inventory Cost for one month
.Range("E9").Formula = "=SUM(C9:D9)"
' Fills in the cells below
.Range("E9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E9:E11"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

My spreadsheets:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485579/multiplying-last-row-from-one-sheet-and-placing-onto-other-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up quite a bit. I didn't bother looping the `sum` cells.
Your code was also missing the calculation for the `Inventory Cost`

```
Sub test()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Sourcews As Worksheet: Set Sourcews = wb.Worksheets("DATA")
    Dim Destinationws As Worksheet: Set Destinationws = wb.Worksheets("Report")

    With Sourcews
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 1), .Cells(lRow, 1)).Copy Destination:=Destinationws.Cells(9, 2)
        .Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 3), .Cells(lRow, 3)).Copy Destination:=Destinationws.Cells(9, 3)
        .Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 7), .Cells(lRow, 7)).Copy Destination:=Destinationws.Cells(9, 4)
    End With

    With Destinationws
        ' text
        .Cells(12, 2).Value = "Total"
        .Cells(8, 2).Value = "Month"
        .Cells(8, 3).Value = "Production Cost"
        .Cells(8, 4).Value = "Inventory Cost"
        .Cells(8, 5).Value = "Total Cost"
        .Cells(8, 3).Value = "Production Cost"
        .Cells(14, 1).Value = "Figure below illustrates the production unit, and the demand time series for the past year; as well as the forecast for the following three months."
        .Cells(28, 1).Value = "Figure below illustrates the inventory levels for the past year, as well as the forecast for the following three months."
        .Cells(42, 1).Value = "Regards,"
        ' Inventory Cost calculation needed
        .Cells(9, 4).Value = .Cells(9, 4).Value ' * another value?
        .Cells(10, 4).Value = .Cells(10, 4).Value ' * another value?
        .Cells(11, 4).Value = .Cells(11, 4).Value ' * another value?
        ' footer totals
        .Cells(12, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(10, 3), .Cells(11, 3))
        .Cells(12, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(9, 4), .Cells(10, 4), .Cells(11, 4))
        .Cells(12, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(12, 3), .Cells(12, 4))
        ' right totals
        .Cells(9, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(9, 3), .Cells(9, 4))
        .Cells(10, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(10, 3), .Cells(10, 4))
        .Cells(11, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(11, 3), .Cells(11, 4))
        .Columns(2).Resize(, 5).ColumnWidth = 13.71
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is great. I will test this out within the hour and let you know. Inventory calculation is completed but I didn't include it.

Comment: Took me over an hour to get it lol. I've edited the code to show you where to modify the inventory calculation. I'll check in on you tomorrow.

Comment: I am implimenting this now, I really appreciate the time spent. Just a question as I'm working on it, will this code be upgradable? As in if I add more rows, the inventory cost will be updated?

Comment: All good. I wrote and rewrote several times where I had loops built and automatic detection of last rows / columns but it was overkill. This code is much cleaner and more understandable so it should be much easier to upgrade as needed.  I you add more rows on the `DATA` sheet, it will correctly detect the correct numbers for you.